# jQuery each() to return false and start up again

Tags: attributes, clone, jquery

I am having problems with the each() function. What I like to is to return false; and then start up again. You'll see the each() function is repeating only the first link. I would like the each link to clone each $('.ms-PostTitle a')  ... See my code. Please Help!

========HTML======= What the each() function is currently doing :( ....

```
<div class="ms-PostTitle"> 
    <a href="Post.aspx?ID=1">Post #1</a>
</div>
<a href="Post.aspx?ID=1" class="read-more">Read More</a>

<div class="ms-PostTitle"> 
    <a href="Post.aspx?ID=2">Post #2</a>
</div>
<a href="Post.aspx?ID=1" class="read-more">Read More</a>
```

========HTML======= What I like it tooo doo....

```
<div class="ms-PostTitle"> 
    <a href="Post.aspx?ID=1">Post #1</a>
</div>
<a href="Post.aspx?ID=1" class="read-more">Read More</a>

<div class="ms-PostTitle"> 
    <a href="Post.aspx?ID=2">Post #2</a>
</div>
<a href="Post.aspx?ID=2" class="read-more">Read More</a>
```

========jQuery=======

```
    $('.ms-PostTitle a').each(function () {
       var href = $(this).attr('href');         
       $('<a class="read-more" href=' + href + '>Read More</a>').insertAfter('div.ms-PostBody p');
       return false;
});
```

Comment: Why are you having the function return `false` if you want it to keep going? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: RTFM: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: What is div.ms-postbody? You need to post more of your HTML. Or, preferably, a jsfiddle.

Comment: Also, those two blocks of HTML look **exactly the same** to me.

Comment: Why is the `return false` important? Returning false inside `jQuery.each()` prevents another iteration. **We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false.**

Comment: @Pointy the difference is the `href` of the last link.

Comment: Ok that's it I'm giving up until I wake up today.

Comment: Haha Pointy... Thank you for help. The two blocks have different hrefs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
$('.ms-PostTitle a').each(function () { 
   $('<a>', { text: "Read More", class: "read-more", href: this.href }).insertAfter($(this).parent());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RLa5C/1/

Comment: Thank you Nicola Peluchetti! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Hi Nicola, your solution is not working in ie7 or ie8. Can you me help again?

Comment: @user952851 IE8 and IE7 need `"` when defining object properties (this is something i discovered now :) ), so this should work http://jsfiddle.net/RLa5C/3/